# How do I use pkgsrc?

Tags: netbsd, pkgsrc

I'm running NetBSD in a virtual machine. Documentation and explanations on how to use pkgsrc are scarce. Let's say I want to install vim for NetBSD. What would I type? Do I need a URL? Do I need a specific version? Do I need to set up a directory for building the source of vim?

Comment: Sorry, dude, but as a former long-term user of NetBSD (this being >10 years ago), I think claiming `pkgsrc` was »scarcely« documented is just utterly wrong.  https://www.netbsd.org/docs/pkgsrc/

Answer (score 4):

As Andreas said, pkgsrc is very well documented. [Follow the pkgsrc guide](https://www.netbsd.org/docs/pkgsrc/) and you should be in business in no time

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you've unpacked the pkgsrc tree into `/home/melab/pkgsrc`. Then you can build gvim as follows:

```
cd /home/melab/pkgsrc/editors/gvim
make package install clean
```

Note that `make` might be `/usr/pkg/bin/bmake` if you bootstrapped pkgsrc yourself with default options, though NetBSD `/usr/bin/make` is really bmake.
This very simple explanation glosses over all the fine tuning that's possible by editing the pkgsrc settings file (`/etc/mk.conf` or perhaps `/usr/pkg/etc/mk.conf`) - for that you would need to check the extensive documentation.